# CSS Grid is that working with e-mail clients?

Tags: css, html-email, css-grid, email-client

I am trying to create an e-mail signature with CSS Grid, however after adding the e-mail to a signature option of mac mail, it's shows the mail, but the css is stripped off. Do you know if this works? Using CSS Grid for e-mail signatures?

Comment: You can get an answer quickly by searching the web. Here is a simple answer from an [article](https://medium.com/action-rocket/building-email-with-css-grid-emailweekly-redesign-week-2-93b949c3183e): "There isn’t support in most webmail clients, nor in Gmail App or in older email clients like Outlook"

Answer (score 4):

CSS Grid has very little support in emails. https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-display-grid/

Think tables and such - it's dark ages in email! There's plenty of online courses about this.